# Is csrf token still necessary for React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, cors

I'm using JWT for auth in React. If the following are true, is `csrf-token` or `x-xsrf-token` still necessary to prevent CSRF attacks?

1. I have already setup `CORS` in my ExpressJS backend to allow only my frontend (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/`) to access the API resources on the server
2. My `access_token` used for authorizing request is stored in React's state (e.g. with Context API)
3. Inside my `HttpOnly` cookies, there is only the `refresh_token` that is meant to be sent to `/refresh` route to get a new `access_token`

Comment: React is a UI rendering library, it changes nothing at all in regard of security of network requests.

Comment: If your auth model uses JWT sent via a request header or something like that, then a CSRF attack is simply not possible. However, you're susceptible to XSS attacks that could leak the JWT.

Comment: How is 1. relevant? CORS is no defence against CSRF...

Comment: @jub0bs I believe that if for example, CORS only allows `http://localhost:3000`, sites of other origins would not be able to send any request containing my cookies?

Comment: Not true. That's a common misunderstanding about CORS. As an example, try `fetch("https://whatever.example.com", {mode: "no-cors", credentials: "include"})`. If your browser has cookies associated to `whatever.example.com` and `SameSite` doesn't get in the way, your browser _will_ send an authenticated request. The response won't (by default) be accessible to the script, but the request _will_ be sent.

Comment: @jub0bs but my cookie does not store any session id or access token for authentication, just `refresh_token`?

Comment: @WilliamLe Ok, but my point is that, all other things being equal, activating CORS doesn't make you more secure against CSRF.